# How to understand TLS certificate is in PEM or DER format

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

My task is  to get "common name" information from TLS certificate. 
I manage to do that by parsing TLS "certificate"(which comes after "hello server")
message and getting a pointer to certificate and passing to the X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID;

```
p = certificate;//this is a pointer to certificate 
X509 *x;
x = d2i_X509(NULL, &p, certificate_lenght);

if (x == NULL)
{
    fout << " X509 object is null " << std::endl;
    return;
}
fout << " no x509  error " << endl;
X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID(X509_get_subject_name(x),NID_commonName, peer_CN, 256);
```

I hope I am doing right things .

My question I design my logic for "DER" format can this information come in "PEM" format . 
If yes how can I understand if the certificate is in PEM or DER format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificate sent during TLS handshake is always a binary data in DER. You don't need to care about PEM there.

If you want to use the same code to load the certificate from other source, then you need to analyze if it is pure text (i.e. only characters in range 32-127). If it is, then most likely you have something PEM. There's no guarantee that you have got the certificate though. You would need to remove the header and footer if they are present there, then base64-decode the rest to get DER, and then you can decode DER.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I searching for this information but couldn't find it in RFC or Wiki or net. If you can share me a document which include this information I will relief :) .

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir Which exactly information are you looking for? DER is the only format for certificates as defined in RFC 5280. PEM and anything else are wrappers and containers for DER certificates. PEM file format as used in OpenSSL is not defined in any standard, though "PEM" term was defined in the RFC and later was renamed to simply base64 :).